# Uml class diagram for java

Tags: java, oop

i am a newbie to java.I am trying to create a library system.

Which classes should be abstract? do i need more classes?

[image: here is how far i got]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you may be asking for homework help.  While we have no issues with that per se, please observe these [dos and don'ts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/338845#338845), and edit your question accordingly.  (Even if this isn't homework, please consider the advice anyway.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you need many classes, Your classes should look like this :

```
class Person{
   //attributes, getters and setters
}

class User extends Person{
   //attributes, getters and setters
}

class Members extends Person{
}

class Librarian extends Person{
}

class Book{
   //attributes, getters and setters
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Person {
    private String FirstName;
    private String LastName;
    private String Gender;
    private String Contact;
    private String Email;

    public Person() {
    }

    public Person(String FirstName, String LastName, String Gender, String Contact, String Email) {
        this.FirstName = FirstName;
        this.LastName = LastName;
        this.Gender = Gender;
        this.Contact = Contact;
        this.Email = Email;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return FirstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String FirstName) {
        this.FirstName = FirstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return LastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String LastName) {
        this.LastName = LastName;
    }

    public String getGender() {
        return Gender;
    }

    public void setGender(String Gender) {
        this.Gender = Gender;
    }

    public String getContact() {
        return Contact;
    }

    public void setContact(String Contact) {
        this.Contact = Contact;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return Email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String Email) {
        this.Email = Email;
    }

}
public class User extends Person {
    private String Password;
    private String Username;
    boolean isEnabled;

    public User() {
    }

    public User(String Password, String Username, boolean isEnabled) {
        this.Password = Password;
        this.Username = Username;
        this.isEnabled = isEnabled;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return Password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String Password) {
        this.Password = Password;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return Username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String Username) {
        this.Username = Username;
    }

    public boolean isIsEnabled() {
        return isEnabled;
    }

    public void setIsEnabled(boolean isEnabled) {
        this.isEnabled = isEnabled;
    }

}
public class Guest extends User {

    public Guest() {
    }

    public Guest(String Password, String Username, boolean isEnabled) {
        super(Password, Username, isEnabled);
    }

    public void App(){

    }
    }
public class Members extends User{

    public Members() {
    }

    public Members(String Password, String Username, boolean isEnabled) {
        super(Password, Username, isEnabled);
    }

}
public class Libararian extends User {

    public Libararian() {

    }
     public Libararian(String Password, String Username, boolean isEnabled) {
        super(Password, Username, isEnabled);
    }

}
public class Book {
    private String Title;
    private String Publisher;
    private String Category;

    public Book(String Title, String Publisher, String Category) {
        this.Title = Title;
        this.Publisher = Publisher;
        this.Category = Category;
    }

    public Book() {
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return Title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String Title) {
        this.Title = Title;
    }

    public String getPublisher() {
        return Publisher;
    }

    public void setPublisher(String Publisher) {
        this.Publisher = Publisher;
    }

    public String getCategory() {
        return Category;
    }

    public void setCategory(String Category) {
        this.Category = Category;
    }

}
```

Comment: Due to multi-level inheritance, Guest(), Members(), Librarian() classes will have all Person() class attributes.Also User() class will have all Person() class attributes. I think this is how you should write your code.